# Why does the width of the depletion region decrease with the increase in doping concentration?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction, depletion-region

Should the depletion region be increasing in width as more and more ions are uncovered at the junction due to the diffusion of majority carriers from one side of the junction to the other? Then why does, the depletion region width of a zener diode which is extensively doped ( compared to a normal power diode ) smaller, allowing for more current flow?

[I was reading about this on this site](https://unacademy.com/content/jee/study-material/physics/zener-breakdown-and-avalanche-breakdown/)

About zener breakdown, trying to compare it with avalanche breakdown

Answer (score 1):

More doping means a shorter depletion region *for a given applied reverse voltage*.

The depletion region grows in length until the (negative) integral of electric field over the length of the region equals to the bias voltage. If the doping is heavy, the electric field is stronger when the doped region is uncovered.

Since the bias voltage is what is fixed, and the electric field is stronger, it takes less length to get to the required voltage.